# How to get ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) for c#?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have just downloaded the VS Community 2019 Version 16.3.9 and I can't seem to find the ASP.NET Web Application(.NET Framework) with the C#. It just only starts with the VB script by default. What should I do to get the same thing with C#.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, you did not download the needed tools after installation.
To download necessary tools, launch the Visual Studio Installer (not the IDE), click on modify, there, you will see myriads of tools, just select the ones you need and download. After successful download, open your IDE and choose your desired framework to work on.

Wish you success.

Sorry for adding this as an answer even though it will help you but nevertheless, I should have added it as a comment but I have less than 50 reputations

Comment: Thank you, I just restart my computer and now it's fine.

Comment: Good to hear that. Happy coding